# How to edit data table column header names using c#?

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

I have some logical block in my C# program, as I am new to C# programming.

I have a data-table with duplicate header column names. I have to change my duplicate header like concatenate the name of the prior column to make these headers unique. Table names are coming dynamically.

Current datatable dTable

```
 ID |Name|Age| School |  Name | state| Part| Country|Division|Part
```

Expected dTable

```
 ID |Name|Age| School |  Name+school | state| Part| Country|Division|Part+Division
```

What I have tried and blocked here below

```
public DataTable RemoveDuplicateRows(DataTable dTable)
{
    string[] columnNames = dTable.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(x => x.ColumnName).ToArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < columnNames.Length; i++)
    {
        columnNames[i] = columnNames[i].Split('.')[0].Trim();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < columnNames.Length; i++)
    {
        // create nested loop for compare current values with actual value of arr
        for (int j = i + 1; j < columnNames.Length; j++)
        {
            if (columnNames[i] == columnNames[j])
            {
                var previous = columnNames[i - 1];
                var current = columnNames[i];
                columnNames[i] = current + previous;

                // blocked here
                // only one header is concatenating
                // how can I add this newly edited columns to my datatable
            }
        }
    }

    return dTable; //cant get updated column headers
}
```

Comment: Your code isn't editing the column names, it's editing the strings in an array

Comment: how can i do that? could you help? how can i add these column names to my datatable? even though its not concatenating all duplicate headers! any hope?

Comment: `someTable.Columns[3].ColumnName='Other Name'` or `someTable.Columns["Name"].ColumnName="Other Name"` are enough. You haven't posted anything that shows *duplicate* names though. It's not even possible to have duplicate column names, you'd get a [DuplicateNameException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.duplicatenameexception?view=netcore-3.1) if you tried to do that. Are you referring to the [DataColumn.Caption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.caption?view=netcore-3.1) property perhaps? Where did this DataTable come from?

Comment: I All colomn names are dynamic.datatable comes from sp actualy like name,name.1,name.2.I have to remove .1,.2 etc and instead of that i need to append prior colom name

Comment: This has nothing to do with duplicate column names. Do you really need to change the names? Or is changing the caption enough? As for the names, I posted how to do that - just set the `ColumnName` property. Your code doesn't do that, it retrieves the strings, so everything after the first line is pointless. Loop over the *column objects*, not their names, and set the `ColumnName` property to whatever you want

Comment: but the challenge is all dynamic here. In column header i need to find what are the duplicates,and i have to add prior name.We dont know the column name before in this case.Any postion any coloumn can repeat

Comment: You asked how to change the column name. The answer is to set the `ColumnName` property. I have no idea how you want to generate that name. There are no "prior" names in a DataTable. There are no duplicate column names either. What you posted would only be possible if the *captions* were different. And as you commented above, the names don't even look like what was posted in the question

Comment: You should post code that actually reproduces the problem with actual sample data and names, explaining what you want the result to be. `name.1` is neither `Name` nor `Name+school`, which is a rather weird column name itself. One would expect `School Name`, `Name of School` or even `Name School`

Comment: i actually meant  name.1 should change  "Name School" pls dont bother about the column names like name,school etc..these column names are coming from SP.so i have to find out the column headers,which are repeating and i have to change duplucate coloumn like above mentioned